# 'SFDX' is not recognized as an internal or external command in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx

trying to practice 
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx?trail_id=sfdx_get_started

but getting SFDX error, mind you sfdx successfully installed and already I finished other modules of trailhead using usual vcmd prompt, only when trying with VS code I am getting error

[image: VS code error for SFDX here]

Comment: If this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238917/salesforce-cli-is-not-installed-it-aint-so), would you please go through the same debugging steps? For example, show us how you have configured your `PATH`, and what is echoed in the terminal if you do `echo %PATH%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing out the terminal and reopening a new one.

Or close out VS Code and re-open.

If you installed the SFDX CLI while the terminal was already open then this may be the issue.

Comment: yes restarted the entire machine worked for me